# How to dock Firebug in browser window?

Tags: macos, firefox, firebug

How to dock Firebug in browser window after I opened in a new window? With Firefox 3.0.8 and Firebug 1.3 on Mac OS X 10.5 I can't get it docked in the browser window back. :(

Comment: This seems to be an old question. I just want to provide an updated solution: open Tools/Web Developer/Firebug/Firebug UI LoCation/Bottom

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How to fix the problem

Background: firefox 10.0.10

Steps:
Close Firebug if you have it open -> Go to Firefox menu -> select the "Web developer" option -> select "Firebug" from all the options listed -> Select "Firebug UI location" from all the options -> Choose Top, Button, Left or Right depending on your preference.

This should fix your problem. The "Firebug UI location" in the detached Firebug window doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on FF v26.0. The selected value is already "bottom", but Firebug continues to open undocked on pressing F12.

Comment: Re: (The "Firebug UI location" in the detached Firebug window doesn't work.) The bug has been fixed. It works in OSX now.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you just close the window. When you open Firebug again, it will be docked.

While I was trying to figure this out, I clicked on the bug in the top left corner, while Firebug was open and docked, and selected "Always Open In New Window." Then I had the same problem.

To disable that option while Firebug is open as a Window, select View (in the OS X menu at the top of the screen while the Firebug window is in the foreground) > Options > Always Open In New Window.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Firebug icon , Choose Firebug UI Location and then choose bottom , it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Resolved by following this:

Right click firebug icon in status bar. Select "On for all web pages"

Answer (score 1):

I Couldn’t dock the firebug window back to the Browser-window. Neither via buttons, nor via menu.

Reseting the firebug-settings solved the problem for me. Luckily, I didn’t changed them ever.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the firebug window and click the firebug icon again.  It will once again be "docked".

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for me. Even setting the prefs 'openInWindow' in Profiles/yourprofile.default/prefs.js to false won't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. Somehow, one of my firebug settings was being stored in my Firefox profile, and I couldn't figure out how to revert it. So, I took the nuclear option and deleted and then recreated my Firebug profile, following these instructions from Mozilla: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager#Creating_a_new_profile

WARNING: This should only be a last resort, as it will remove all of your previous saved settings, add-ons etc. This was not a big deal for me, because I use Chrome as my default browser and only user Firefox for debugging websites using Firebug. But for others, I suspect this might be throwing the baby out with the bathwater, so just wanted to make it clear that there are tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the small superimposed double rectangle icon on the far right of the firebug window, and dock and undock the firebug widget.

[image]

Comment: This is only available in Windows, not OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the small superimposed double rectangle icon on the far right of the firebug window, and dock and undock the firebug widget.

It worked for me in Windows