# How to dock the Firefox Browser Console

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

How do I dock the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) window in Firefox?

The Browser Console currently opens in a separate window. I'd prefer for it to be docked to the bottom of the main window.

There's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709941/how-to-dock-firebug-in-browser-window) for Firebug.

Answer (score 3):

There is no stock way to dock the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) to a specific window. The Browser Console is for the entirety of the Firefox browser. What it shows is not limited to a single window. Thus, from a user interface point of view, it does not make sense to have it be docked to a single window.

It might be possible to create an add-on which opens an equivalent page that is in a bottom bar.

Comment: thanks ! it's a shame this console should behave like the menu / tabs of firefox

Answer (score 1):

The best I could do was manually to dock Browser Console window and Firefox window in my desktop environment (Gnome on Fedora) so that they are both visible when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way with the built-in console.  However, the 'Web Developer Extension' add-on console has toggles to dock to a window, but also several additional useful layouts.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. The question was how to do it, not whether it does.